# Add new domain system on Erpnext

Tags: erpnext, frappe

I've installed ErpNext using Docker easy install method. I didn't see any domain option while setting up first time. I want to add `Non Profit` and `Education` domain to the Erpnext app.
Please help me to add this two domain to the ErpNext app setup with docker installation.

ErpNext: v14.15.1

Answer (score 0):

As of Version 14, ERPNext has been splitting domains into separate applications. You can read more on this in the [ERPNext Version 14 Migration Guide](https://github.com/frappe/erpnext/wiki/Migration-Guide-to-ERPNext-version-14). You will have to install these apps separately after ERPNext on your Bench & Sites.

```bash
bench get-app non_profit # install apps on bench
bench get-app education
bench --site {site} install-app education non_profit # install apps on site
```

Here are the individual projects for your reference:

- [Non-Profit App](https://github.com/frappe/non_profit)
- [Education App](https://github.com/frappe/education)

These applications may not have any additional Frappa app dependencies. However, you may run the `get-app` command with `--resolve-deps` flag just in case.